# Django Unable to load the SpatiaLite library extension mod_spatialite on Ubuntu

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite, ubuntu-16.04, spatialite

I'm trying to run sqlite3 with spatialite but when i run

```
 $ python manage.py makemigrations
```

im getting the error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Unable to load the
>   SpatiaLite library extension "mod_spatialite" because:
>   mod_spatialite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

I'm using

- Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial
- Django 1.11
- Python 3.5.2

and have installed the packages:

- spatialite-bin
- spatialite-gui
- spatialite-gui-dbg
- python-pyspatialite

I also tried adding `SPATIALITE_LIBRARY_PATH = 'mod_spatialite'` but it still didnt work.

my complete traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/spatialite/base.py", line 60, in get_new_connection
    cur.execute("SELECT load_extension(%s)", (self.spatialite_lib,))
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: mod_spatialite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 110, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 282, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/spatialite/base.py", line 65, in get_new_connection
    six.reraise(ImproperlyConfigured, ImproperlyConfigured(new_msg), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/spatialite/base.py", line 60, in get_new_connection
    cur.execute("SELECT load_extension(%s)", (self.spatialite_lib,))
  File "/home/marcelo/.virtualenvs/smart-eye-agora-vai/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Unable to load the SpatiaLite library extension "mod_spatialite" because: mod_spatialite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to install libsqlite3-mod-spatialite by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-mod-spatialite
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue by changing

```
SPATIALITE_LIBRARY_PATH = 'mod_spatialite'
```

to

```
SPATIALITE_LIBRARY_PATH = 'mod_spatialite.so'
```

as per this [comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29645#comment:1).

Answer (score 0):

I solved by reinstalling every package and adding every spatialite package I could find using synaptic package manager. The list of packages i have installed:

- librasterlite2-1
- libspatialite-dbg
- libspatialite7
- libsqlite3-mod-rasterlite2
- libsqlite3-mod-spatialite
- spatialite-bin
- spatialite-gui
- spatialite-gui-dbg
- python-pyspatialite

Answer (score 0):

I am running **sqlite3** on **Ubuntu 20.04**, got error to load spatialite extension

```
sqlite> SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');
Error: mod_spatialite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have install the following command on terminal. Here in technical terms, **apt** provides a high level interface for package management and **apt-get** provides a low level interface.

```
sudo apt install libsqlite3-mod-spatialite
```